# Simple PHPUnit one about getting a generic mocked object

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit

Test method:

```php
public function convert(AbstractMessage $message)
{
    $data = array();

    // Text conversion
    $text = $message->getText();

    if(null !== $text) {
        if(!is_string($text) && (is_object($text)
            && !method_exists($text, '__toString'))) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException(gettype($text), 'string');
        }

        $data['text'] = (string) $text;
    }
}
```

How can I mock a generic object (no matter the class) that has a `__toString` method?

Comment: You don't have to mock it. You can just create a real object of yourself to use in your test. What I didnt understand from your question is what exactly you are trying to test.

Are you trying to test whether an object has __toString method ?

Comment: You mean an empty class? I'm testing @expectedException

Comment: Yes. But again. What are you trying to test? The method that checks whether the class has a `__toString` method ?

Comment: @Alex exactly. If it's an object without __toString, expect a UnexpectedTypeException.

Comment: See my answer. Can you take it on from there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// UnderTest.php

class UnderTest
{
    public function hasTostring($obj)
    {
        return method_exists($obj, '__toString');
    }
}



// Observer.php

class ObserverTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testHasTostring()
    {

        $tester = new UnderTest();
        $with = new WithToString();
        $without = new WithoutToString();

        $this->assertTrue($tester->hasTostring($with));
        $this->assertFalse($tester->hasTostring($without));

        // this automatically calls to string
        // and if the method toString doesnt exists - returns E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
        // so this line should work
        $x = $with . '';


        // but this shouldnt work, because the method doesnt exist
        // therefore you are supposed to get an exception
        $this->setExpectedException('PHPUnit_Framework_Error');
        $x = $without . '';
    }
}


        class WithToString
        {
            public function __toString() { return 'hi'; }
        }

        class WithoutToString{}
```

Comment: Just bump in this two classes into your test file. It's ok to have them there instead of trying to mock something.

Comment: OK fine, can't imagine it was so simply as creating a class :)